# branch name autocompletion for mercurial in zsh

Tags: mercurial, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I was very excited about zsh but I occurred a big problem.

Autocompletion for `hg update` doesn't work for me. I did include `zsh_completion`  file (from newest mercurial source) in my `.zshrc` file like this (after moving to home directory):

```
fpath=("$HOME/.zsh_completion" $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I type `hg up def<tab>` and no completion is happening.

I also tried `rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit` and didn't help as well. I'm using `zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0)` and `oh-my-zsh`.

My actual `.zshrc`:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/kayne/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
#ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(colored-man colorize ruby rails brew osx mercurial zsh-syntax-highlighting)

# User configuration

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/kayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/kayne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/kayne/.rvm/bin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# PostgreSQL App
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

# This loads NVM
[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh

fpath=("$HOME/.zsh_completion" $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
# everything below is commented out
```

Comment: you did start a new shell or re-sourced the .zshrc after you added it to your .zshrc, yes?

Comment: Of course… 
I did `source ~/.zshrc` and even closed terminal app and open it again.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using OS X 10.10 and I installed newest zsh version through homebrew (just `brew install zsh`).

Comment: Are you using the most recent version from `https://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/contrib/zsh_completion` (click on the "raw" link in the sidebar to download the actual file)? That should enable branch completion properly. See the file comment for how to install it.

Comment: Yes I do. Today I downloaded source (from https://www.mercurial-scm.org) and used `contrib/zsh_completions`. But even right now I downloaded version you provided and it's still not working. I just posted my `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo! I've found a problem. I've got `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.8/functions` folder with `_hg` file. This is file with some old functions from different version of zsh. I assume `5.0.8` was OS X 10.10 native version of this shell. I installed `5.1.1` from homebrew. But `5.0.8` functions folder stayed - and he was added at the end of the `$fpath`. So it overwrited my `zsh_completion` file which path was before in `$fpath`.

So I've got the last question. Is it safe to remove `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.8/functions` or even `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.8`? Or better don't touch it… at least when everything works?

Comment: Edit your `$fpath`, don't touch that install. You must be doing something wrong if `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.8/functions` shows up in `$fpath` when you run 5.1.1; it shouldn't be there by default.

Comment: Ok, so you see, now I'm confused. Because in my `.zshrc` there is no path to `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.8/functions` and yet it does appear when I type `echo $fpath`. Where could $fpath be set apart of `.zshrc`?

Comment: There are many possibilities. Try `zsh -x` or `zsh -xl` and inspect your init sequence for assignments to `fpath`. (Keep in mind that everything is not necessarily printed.)